# Javascript-How to make overlay tag on the pie chart by Chartist js

Tags: javascript, pie-chart, chartist.js

I wana know how use chartist js to make this effect.
When the mouse enter, the tag shows up.
[image: Picture form chart js]
I encountered two issue:
1.I know how to add event listener.The data type 'slice' only contains center position.
data type 'label' contain the position what I want but I don't want label shows up so I set showLabel:false.
2.I tried to append html and set z-index,x position, y position but not worked.
How can I do?

=====================(update current result)============================
This project is for business so I mark out the title.
[image: Picture form chart js]
Currently I have no idea how to do.
Here is My code:

```
new Chartist.Pie('#pieAppUsageChart', AppUsagePiedata, {
        height: 300,
        showLabel: false
    }).on('draw', function(data){
        if(data.type === 'slice'){
            console.log(data);
            $('#pieAppUsageChart').find("."+data.series.className).on('mouseenter',function(){
            }).on('mouseleave',function(){
            });
        }
    });
```

Comment: Kindly show us your code what you have done so far!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all thanks for using Chartist :-)

If you're using event delegation you can add one listener to rule them all. You then also don't need to use the `draw` event, since the listener will be valid even when child nodes will be updated / re-created.

Just add this piece of code to catch all mouseenter / mouseleave events using delegation:

```
$('#your-chart').on('mouseenter', '.ct-slice-pie', function() {
  var $slice = $(this);
  // Code for showing tooltip, you can use any tooltip library like tooltipster
  // You can get meta data from your slices using $slice.getAttribute('ct:meta');
});
```

Comment: Thanks for answer. But I tried to add bootstrap tooltip, It didn't work. OTZ

Comment: Hey gkunz, I found your example code in[JS Bin](http://jsbin.com/xojezu/edit?html,js,output) I will study it.!! Thanks for sharing your knowledge. :)